# Flutter: How I can fix page controller animation error

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, controller, widget

I have a page containing a page view slider with a page controller and I get this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>
> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. E/flutter (
>
> 7013): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no
>
> longer stable. E/flutter ( 7013): To safely refer to a widget's
>
> ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by
>
> calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
>
> didChangeDependencies() method.

I'm trying to solve it but I can't and I don't know the reason for this error.
This my code which I use:

```
var pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  var pageViewModelData = List<PageViewData>();

  Timer sliderTimer;
  var currentShowIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageViewModelData.add(PageViewData(
      titleText: 'Cape Town',
      subText: 'Extraordinary five-star\noutdoor activites',
      assetsImage: 'assets/images/explore_2.jpg',
    ));
    pageViewModelData.add(PageViewData(
      titleText: 'Find best deals',
      subText: 'Extraordinary five-star\noutdoor activites',
      assetsImage: 'assets/images/explore_1.jpg',
    ));
    pageViewModelData.add(PageViewData(
      
      titleText: 'Find best deals',
      subText: 'Extraordinary five-star\noutdoor activites',
      assetsImage: 'assets/images/explore_3.jpg',
    ));

    sliderTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4), (timer) {
      if (currentShowIndex == 0) {
        pageController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
      } else if (currentShowIndex == 1) {
        pageController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
      } else if (currentShowIndex == 2) {
        pageController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sliderTimer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I get the error start from this line:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this issue! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Value of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` is not not ready in `initState()` 
You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` 
code snippet

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print('width ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.width}');
      sliderTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4), (timer) {
        if (currentShowIndex == 0) {
          pageController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        } else if (currentShowIndex == 1) {
          pageController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        } else if (currentShowIndex == 2) {
          pageController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        }
      });
    });
```

working demo

[image]

output

```
I/flutter ( 1876): width 411.42857142857144
```

full code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Tutorial',
    home: new AnimatedIconExample(),
  ));
}

class AnimatedIconExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedIconExampleState createState() => _AnimatedIconExampleState();
}

class _AnimatedIconExampleState extends State<AnimatedIconExample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController pageController = PageController();
  AnimationController controller;
  Timer sliderTimer;
  var currentShowIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print('width ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.width}');
      sliderTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4), (timer) {
        if (currentShowIndex == 0) {
          pageController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        } else if (currentShowIndex == 1) {
          pageController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        } else if (currentShowIndex == 2) {
          pageController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
        }
      });
    });


  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            child: Center(
              child: AnimatedIcon(
                  icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close, progress: controller),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              controller.reverse();
              pageController.animateToPage(0,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.linear);
            },
          ),
          title: Text("Animated PageView Controller")),
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildPage0(),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.blue),
          Container(color: Colors.yellow),
          Container(color: Colors.pink),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  show(int page) {
    controller.forward();
    pageController.animateToPage(page,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.linear);
  }

  Container buildPage0() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(onTap: () => show(1), title: Center(child: Text("Green"))),
          ListTile(onTap: () => show(2), title: Center(child: Text("Blue"))),
          ListTile(onTap: () => show(3), title: Center(child: Text("Yellow"))),
          ListTile(onTap: () => show(4), title: Center(child: Text("Pink"))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```